# Copying files using wildcard ending in ".*"

Tags: vbscript, wildcard

I currently have the task to write a script, that will run as a scheduled task, which moves Log-Files to another folder. Everytime a log file hits a size of 50MB a new one is started and the old one is renamed.

The Files that my script should move are named like "MyApp.log.X", where X is a number greater than or equal 1, which can be 1 or more digits long.
The Log-File which is currently in use is named MyApp.log and should not be moved by the sript.
Also, there are other files in the same folder, which are no Log-Files at all and shall not be moved.

My plan was to use the FileSystemObject-method MoveFile in combination with a wildcard to copy the desired files. Code looks like this:

```
fso.CopyFile "F:\MyApp\MyApp.log.*","F:\MyApp\Archive"
```

As far as I know this should have the desired effect of choosing only the Log-Files with a dot and 0 or more signs at the end, so the file "MyApp.log" should be ruled out.
But in reality, no matter which method of the FSO I use "MyApp.log" is always copied/deleted/you-name-it, along with all the files that I actually intend to copy/delete/you-name-it.

I googled and found a blog entry from 2007 where the author stated that there is some interesting behaviour dragged around with Windows wildcards from back in the DOS-days.

Relevant Section:

> For example, if your pattern ends in .* , the .* is ignored. Without
> this rule, the pattern *.* would match only files that contained a
> dot, which would break probably 90% of all the batch files on the
> planet, as well as everybody's muscle memory, since everybody running
> Windows NT 3.1 grew up in a world where *.* meant all files.

So my questions are:

- Can anyone confirm that this behaviour is (still) actually present in VBS on Windows Script Host? If not, can someone spot a mistake in my wildcard-expression?
- Whether the "bug" actually exists in VBS or not, does someone have suggestions for a different approach to copy only the desired files?

Thanks in advance to any suggestions and comments!

Textsource: ["How did wildcards work in MS-DOS?" by Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071217-00/?p=24143)
(link updated on 14.11.2022)

Comment: I can confirm the behavior. As a workaround you may want to shell out to `robocopy` (`robocopy F:\MyApp F:\MyApp\Archive MyApp.log.* /xf MyApp.log /mov`) or switch to PowerShell.

Comment: Well it seems robocopy has the same issue with wildcards, it also copies more than it should.
Copy-item in Powershell actually interprets the wildcards correctly, but i will probably stick to my VBS script, since it already works (with a little workaround) and I don't know much about Powershell yet.
But thanks anyways!

Comment: Please note the file exclusion `/xf MyApp.log`. It's there for a reason.

Comment: Sorry i was to fast when trying it. I will give it another try!